# Joining 1 MySQL row with several results

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have a problem listing articles and their respective tags, maybe someone can help me.

Imagine the query:

```
select *.articles, tags.tag_name 

from articles

left join tags on tags.article_id = articles.article_id

where articles.article_id = 1
```

This would work fine if the article only had one tag. The problem is if the articles has more than 1 tag, then I get 1 row per tag for the same article. If I want to show these articles in a for each it shows to many of the same article.

Is there a way to keep this in one row or do I need to use two queries, one for the article info and one for the tags? This would be bad since a list of 50 artciles would require 50 queries to show their tags.

Answer (score 0):

If an article can have more than one tag you have to create an intermediate table which will contain id of articles and tags, so you will be able to link many articles with many tags.

Then your query will be

```
select *.articles, tags.tag_name 

from articles

inner join rel_tags on articles.article_id = rel_tags.article and articles.article_id = 1

inner join tags on rel_tags.tag = tags.tag_id
```

Comment: yeah i have a table for the relations. I tried your 'inner' way but get the same problem, 2 articles with 2 tags each gives me 4 rows.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, it seems GROUP_CONCAT is the best way, but I don't understand the behaviour you have...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `GROUP_CONCAT` which by default returns a comma seperated list of values over your grouped expression. eg.

```
select a.article_id, GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_name)
from articles a
    left join tags t using (article_id)
where a.article_id = 1
group by a.article_id
```

Or run the one query with the join and get duplicated article information, which you can then re-combine programatically. This can be automated by using an ORM.

Comment: this only works if i want just one article it seems. I want a list of articles with their tags, in 1 query.

Comment: If you want all articles, then just remove the where clause, which is limiting it to one article (as per your original query).

Comment: Hey, thanks but if i remove the where clause i still get 1 row and all the tags of every article grouped in one colum. What i wanted is 1 row per article with grouped tags for that article, maybe i should make a new question? grrr :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function:

```
SELECT *.articles, GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_name)
FROM articles
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.article_id = articles.article_ID
WHERE articles.article_id = 1
GROUP BY articles.article_id
```

It'll convert those extra rows into a single field.

Comment: i guess that would work, the problem is i want to show a list of articles and their respective tags. Not just the article id 1. IF i try without the article id 1 part it only returns 1 (the first article) row and merges all the tags in 1 field hehe